# Extend simple DHCP address range to include more addresses

Tags: server, dhcp

For a small business, I setup a small server running Ubuntu 14.04 that provides DHCP and other services. I use the isc-dhcp-server package. It currently serves 240 possible addresses, but now we have run out of addresses (everyone has a PC, cellphone, and laptop at their desk).

My configuration is simple (from `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`):

```
option domain-name "foobar.com";
option domain-name-servers 172.19.2.10;
option routers 172.19.2.1;
subnet 172.19.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 172.19.2.11 172.19.2.251;
}
```

I'd like to add another set of addresses ranging from 172.19.3.11 to 172.19.3.251, which can still access systems on the 172.19.2 subnet.

I tried adding this:

```
# extend the range by another 240 addresses
subnet 172.19.3.0 netmask 255.255.254.0 {
       range 172.19.3.11 172.19.3.251;
}
```

and changing the netmask for the first subnet declaration to this:

```
subnet 172.19.2.0 netmask 255.255.254.0
```

However, when I restart isc-dhcp-server (using service isc-dhcp-server restart), I get an error.

So, two questions:

1. is the syntax correct in dhcpd.conf to extend the served network by another 240 addresses?
2. do I have to change the netmask of the DHCP server itself to 255.255.254.0 (its current address is 172.19.2.10 with netmask of 255.255.255.0)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need just one subnet:

```
option domain-name "foobar.com";
option domain-name-servers 172.19.2.10;
option routers 172.19.2.1;
subnet 172.19.2.0 netmask 255.255.254.0 {
    range 172.19.2.10 172.19.2.250;
    range 172.19.3.10 172.19.3.250;
}
```

And all devices on the network which use static IPs (especially your DHCP server) must have their netmask changed to 255.255.254.0 in their network configuration.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this yesterday. I changed the netmask of my DHCP/DNS system's 'em1' network interface (whose address is 172.19.2.10) to 255.255.254.0 using ifconfig(8), and also changed the netmask of four internal servers. But I then had a problem where client systems no longer had internet access. I could not ping www.google.com or find any non cached web page addresses. The network router, which is at address 172.19.2.1, has a netmask of 255.255.255.0. Would this have to change as well? I'm thinking that responses cannot get back to the requesting client from the router?

Comment: I said very clearly that all devices on the network must have their netmask changed.